# Credential Management API in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to the credential management api in react but i am getting error:

'PasswordCredential' is not defined

my code:

```
const cred = new PasswordCredential({
        id: this.state.user,
        password: this.state.password
      })
      navigator.credentials.store(cred)
```

when trying to create new PasswordCredential.
Please help me out
Thanks

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try `window.PasswordCredential` it whoud work

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/

Comment: @greatisgreat glad to hear that

Comment: Keep helping  others